# LIKE '%[9-15]%' (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-like

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and I would like to ask if it's possible to use the `LIKE` like operator as follows:

```
LIKE '%Ticket [8-14]%'
```

Is this correct or the numbers greater than 9 (10,11, etc etc) will be identified as 1 and 0, 1 and 1, 1 and 2 etc etc.

If this way doesn't work, what can i do to select all the data that contain strings like 'Ticket 10', 'Ticket11' and so on..?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you exactly looking for 8...14 or can the numbers change?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results please? Numbers are not treated the same in a `varchar` for ordering. For example the statement `'12' < '9'` is true.

Comment: @Salman A, in my case it's 8-14

Comment: @Larnu, that's right i'm looking for tickets 8,9,10,11,12,13 and 14.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry that i haven't used sample data, but i haven't figured out how to display tables with data in stackoverflow yet. my bad

Comment: This may help:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no. However, You can do something like:

```
WITH Demo AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('Ticket 1'),
        ('Ticket 7'),
        ('Ticket 8'),
        ('Ticket 10'),
        ('Ticket 12'),
        ('Ticket 15')
    ) T(X)
)
SELECT *
FROM Demo
WHERE X LIKE '%Ticket [8-9]%' OR X LIKE '%Ticket 1[0-4]%'
```

Also, consider normalization - create `TicketNumber` column if you need to query over this value. It's much easier to concatenate `Ticket` and number than parse string. `TicketNumber` could also be easily indexed if needed.

There is also more clever idea to parse numbers:

```
WITH Demo AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('Ticket 1'),
        ('Ticket 7'),
        ('My Ticket 8A'),
        ('Ticket 10'),
        ('Some Ticket 12'),
        ('Ticket 15 other text'),
        ('Ticket 135 and more')
    ) T(X)
)
SELECT *, CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9][0-9][0-9]%',X)!=0 THEN SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9][0-9][0-9]%',X)+7, 3)
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9][0-9]%',X)!=0 THEN SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9][0-9]%',X)+7, 2)
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9]%',X)!=0 THEN SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%Ticket [0-9]%',X)+7, 1)
               END AS int) Number
FROM Demo
```

Column number should now contain simple int value - ready to compare and take part in calculations.

Comment: That's actually a pretty clever idea, i'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

> '%Ticket [8-14]%'

The brackets are used to specify a single character, that's usually specified as a lower and upper range like "[0-9]" or "[a-z]".

Your string would match:

"Ticket 1" through "Ticket 8". The 4 would be ignored because it's already handled by the 8-1 range.

It would not match "Ticket 0" or "Ticket 9" or "Ticket 10".

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach to Pawel's, but a very similar idea:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES('8'),('9'),('10'),('11'),('12'),('13'),('14')) V(TN)
WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE '%Ticket ' + V.TN + '%';
```

If you're using this as a Stored Procedure, you could use a table-value paramter to hold the data instead. Something like:

```
CREATE TYPE numbers AS table (Number int);
GO
CREATE PROC YourProc @TicketNumbers numbers READONLY AS

    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS JOIN @TicketNumbers TN
    WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE 'Ticket ' + CONVERT(varchar(3),TN.Number) + '%';

GO
```

Comment: I tried your first query and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!